# Prevent script using: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD' == 'POST'] from running if other scripts == 'POST'

Tags: php

I have a calculator form included in my sidebar, below a login form.  When a user submits the login form, that action triggers the:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {}
```

statement in my other form.  I tried adding an:

```
if (isset($varOne)) {}
```

statement, using the:

```
$varOne = $_POST['varOne'];
```

from the calculator script, but that didn't work either.  The calculator script continues to run if the login form is submitted.  How must we stop the madness?!

Comment: A combination of both of your attempts... Post your code and we can be more specific...

Comment: Ummm how are your forms layed out? HTML?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing more code. Both the `<form>` tags and the PHP form processing.

Comment: no offense (because i get where you're coming from) but replies like these are unnecessary.  there's no need to post a huge code snippet for such a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the two:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['varOne'])) {
  // calculator button was pressed
}
```

or:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['varOne'])) {
    // calculator button was pressed
  } else {
    // probably a login post
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  I'll accept the answer in a few minutes...since for some reason the site won't let me accept it so soon.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this could be passing extra parameter via get method from `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="somefile.php?formname=login" method="post"> 

</form>
```

And for your calculator form you can put

```
 <form action="somefile.php?formname=calculator" method="post"> 

 </form>
```

Finally, on your form processing script, you can check

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['formname'])){
     if($_GET['formname']=='login'){
           //get login form fields 
          $someVar=$_POST['fieldname']; //etc etc

     }

     if($_GET['formname']=='calculator'){
           //get calculator form fields 
          $someVar=$_POST['fieldname']; //etc etc

     }

   }
?>
```